# Address bar not appears after exitFullscreen - Chrome 85 Mobile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use javascript to toggle fullscreen mode. only in Chrome after `exitFullscreen` address bar not appears.

After exiting fullscreen mode, my screen looks like this, the grey section is my content and the black section is the place of the address bar that is not visible.

[image]

I test it in other browsers like Edge and Firefox. It works.

**Note 1**: the height of the content limited with view height (100vh)

**Note 2**: It only happens in portrait dimension

**Note 3**: It happenes in all sites

Comment: Please report this at https://bugs.chromium.org/

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1125630